# displaying my count results

Tags: php, sql

i have made a query to find how many people have voted for an entry and it goes like this:

```
  $query = "SELECT itemid, COUNT(*) totalcount
FROM jos_sobi2_plugin_reviews
GROUP BY itemid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
";
```

The sql works and produces the following table.

```
entry id      totalcount
--------      ----------
202             5
203             20
204             15
...
```

I only want to display the column `totalcount` and i dont succeed.

maybe someone knows which query should i right on my php?

thanks, ronen!

Comment: if it works in mysql it's working in php, the problem is probably in your php display logic.

Comment: Is your problem that you want the sql query to only return one column, totalcount? Or is your problem how to output only the total count column as html?

Comment: You need to show your PHP display code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(1) totalcount
FROM jos_sobi2_plugin_reviews
GROUP BY itemid
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
";
```

This could work fine

Comment: Uhm "don't use wildchar (*) in COUNT() function" --- ?!?!??!? Any **real** reason for that?

Comment: because that's counting every column if I'm not wrong, if yes, could you atach a reference?

Comment: you're wrong. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Comment: the query works great but it displays the column itemid - but i want to display the column totalcount....how should the query go?

Comment: @ronen: I edited my answer already, it should show only totalcount column

Comment: I did not tell you to remove *

Comment: i want to show on my site the result of the count....and the result is the column total ammount

Comment: so just copy that variable I given you and paste it into your code